# Eighties book about a museum of incredible devices

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

In the early eighties, I got a book from the library (UK) about a museum of incredible devices.

The book was large and colourful.  It might have been called something like “night in the museum” but it wasn’t related to the films.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  How large was this book?  Was it hardback sized or folio sized?  Do you recall any of the devices?  Were they fantastic (magic) or technological?

Comment: It was folio sized (12x8 inches maybe bigger). 
They were technological.  One of them was a plate smashing device, it had a long rail down to a wall.

Comment: There was a book published in the early '70s called "Catalog of Fantastic Things" which had various silly/impractical objects described. Nothing about a museum, though, so it's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: That’s not it.  But thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Not a [W. Heath Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) or [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) book/collection?